# Interacting with long-running python script

Tags: python

I have a long running Python script which collect tweets from Twitter, and I would like to know how its doing every once in awhile.

Currently, I am using the `signal` library to catch interrupts, at which point I call my print function.  Something like this:

```
import signal

def print_info(count):
    print "#Tweets:", count

#Print out the process ID so I can interrupt it for info
print 'PID:', os.getpid()

#Start listening for interrupts
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, functools.partial(print_info, tweet_count))
```

And whenever I want my info, I open up a new terminal and issue my interrupt:

```
$kill -USR1 <pid>
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I am aware I could have my script something at scheduled intervals, but I am more interested in knowing on demand, and potentially issuing other commands as well.

Comment: This seems to be an applicable use signal library. Why do you think there is a better way?

Comment: You could have thread listen on a socket for connections and then write information to the socket when a client connects.

Comment: @MrAlias I am planning to have more than one "print" method, and from what I can tell there are a finite of interrupts I can use, so I thought maybe there was a different way to interact with my program during runtime.

Comment: If there are only just one or a few commands, I think signal is enough. But if you have a lot different commands, I will prefer using a thread listen on a socket or just read file for accepting commands.

Comment: It might be helpful to know that `signal.signal` sends both the signal number as well as the frame, and you can extract information from the frame, like global and local variables (possibly tweet_counts and other desired status objects...).  Otherwise if you like the idea of save info to a file the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module would be a good option.

Comment: rsync uses the `USR1` approach, for reference. Is your question actually how to interact when you need multiple ways to interact, or just to get status? The question text doesn't seem to match the title.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a signal to process would interrupt the process. Below you will find an approach that uses dedicated thread to emulate python console. The console is exposed as a unix socket.

```
import traceback
import importlib
from code import InteractiveConsole
import sys
import socket
import os
import threading
from logging import getLogger

# template used to generate file name
SOCK_FILE_TEMPLATE = '%(dir)s/%(prefix)s-%(pid)d.socket'

log = getLogger(__name__)


class SocketConsole(object):
    '''
    Ported form :eventlet.backdoor.SocketConsole:.
    '''
    def __init__(self, locals, conn, banner=None):  # pylint: diable=W0622
        self.locals = locals
        self.desc = _fileobject(conn)
        self.banner = banner
        self.saved = None

    def switch(self):
        self.saved = sys.stdin, sys.stderr, sys.stdout
        sys.stdin = sys.stdout = sys.stderr = self.desc

    def switch_out(self):
        sys.stdin, sys.stderr, sys.stdout = self.saved

    def finalize(self):
        self.desc = None

    def _run(self):
        try:
            console = InteractiveConsole(self.locals)
            # __builtins__ may either be the __builtin__ module or
            # __builtin__.__dict__ in the latter case typing
            # locals() at the backdoor prompt spews out lots of
            # useless stuff
            import __builtin__
            console.locals["__builtins__"] = __builtin__
            console.interact(banner=self.banner)
        except SystemExit:  # raised by quit()
            sys.exc_clear()
        finally:
            self.switch_out()
            self.finalize()


class _fileobject(socket._fileobject):
    def write(self, data):
        self._sock.sendall(data)

    def isatty(self):
        return True

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def readline(self, *a):
        return socket._fileobject.readline(self, *a).replace("\r\n", "\n")


def make_threaded_backdoor(prefix=None):
    '''
    :return: started daemon thread running :main_loop:
    '''
    socket_file_name = _get_filename(prefix)

    db_thread = threading.Thread(target=main_loop, args=(socket_file_name,))
    db_thread.setDaemon(True)
    db_thread.start()
    return db_thread


def _get_filename(prefix):
    return SOCK_FILE_TEMPLATE % {
        'dir': '/var/run',
        'prefix': prefix,
        'pid': os.getpid(),
    }


def main_loop(socket_filename):
    try:
        log.debug('Binding backdoor socket to %s', socket_filename)
        check_socket(socket_filename)

        sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sockobj.bind(socket_filename)
        sockobj.listen(5)
    except Exception, e:
        log.exception('Failed to init backdoor socket %s', e)
        return

    while True:
        conn = None
        try:
            conn, _ = sockobj.accept()
            console = SocketConsole(locals=None, conn=conn, banner=None)
            console.switch()
            console._run()
        except IOError:
            log.debug('IOError closing connection')
        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()


def check_socket(socket_filename):
    try:
        os.unlink(socket_filename)
    except OSError:
        if os.path.exists(socket_filename):
            raise
```

Example program:

```
make_threaded_backdoor(prefix='test')
while True:
    pass
```

Example session:

```
mmatczuk@cactus:~$ rlwrap nc -U /var/run/test-3196.socket
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
3196
>>> quit()
mmatczuk@cactus:~$
```

This is a pretty robust tool that can be used to:

- dump threads,
- inspect process memory,
- attach debugger on demand, [pydev debugger](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) (work for both eclipse and pycharm),
- force GC,
- monkeypatch function definition on the fly

and even more.

Comment: nice. very useful snippets for me. voted up but need to use in python 3

Comment: Here is python 3 version that should work I think: https://hastebin.com/eketewaxes.py

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute '_fileobject'`

Answer (score 0):

I personally write information to a file so that I have it afterwards, although this has the disadvantage of perhaps being slightly slower because it has to write to a file every time or every few times it retrieves a tweet.

Anyways, if you write it to a file `"output.txt"`, you can open up `bash` and either type in `tail output.txt` for the latest 10 lines printed in the file, or you can type `tail -f output.txt`, which continuously updates the terminal prompt with the lines that you are writing to the file. If you wish to stop, just `Ctrl-C`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example long-running program that also maintains a status socket.  When a client connects to the socket, the script writes some status information to the socket.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import argparse
import random
import threading
import socket
import time
import select

val1 = 0
val2 = 0
lastupdate = 0
quit = False

# This function runs in a separate thread.  When a client connects,
# we write out some basic status information, close the client socket,
# and wait for the next connection.
def connection_handler(sock):
    global val1, val2, lastupdate, quit

    while not quit:
        # We use select() with a timeout here so that we are able to catch the
        # quit flag in a timely manner.
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([sock],[],[], 0.5)
        if not rlist:
            continue

        client, clientaddr = sock.accept()
        client.send('%s %s %s\n' % (lastupdate, val1, val2))
        client.close()

# This function starts the listener thread.
def start_listener():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX)

    try:
        os.unlink('/var/tmp/myprog.socket')
    except OSError:
        pass

    sock.bind('/var/tmp/myprog.socket')
    sock.listen(5)

    t = threading.Thread(
        target=connection_handler,
        args=(sock,))
    t.start()

def main():
    global val1, val2, lastupdate

    start_listener()

    # Here is the part of our script that actually does "work".
    while True:
        print 'updating...'
        lastupdate = time.time()
        val1 = val1 + random.randint(1,10)
        val2 = val2 + random.randint(100,200)
        print 'sleeping...'
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except (Exception,KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
        quit=True
        raise
```

You could write a simple Python client to connect to the socket, or you could use something like `socat`:

```
$ socat - unix:/var/tmp/myprog.sock
1403061693.06 6 152
```

Answer (score 0):

I had write a similar application before.

Here is what I did:

When there are only a few commands needed, I just use signal as you did, just for not making it too complicated. By command, I mean something that you want you application to do, such as `print_info` in your post.

But when application updated, there are more different commands needed, I began to use a special thread listening on a socket port or reading a local file for accepting commands. Suppose the application need to support `prinf_info1` `print_info2` `print_info3`, so you can use a client connect to the target port and write *print_info1* to make the application execute command *print_info1* (Or just write *print_info1* to a local file if you are using the reading local file mechanism).

When using the listening on a socket port mechanism, the disadvantage is it will take a bit more work to write a client to give commands, the advantage is you can give orders anywhere.

When using the reading a local file mechanism, the disadvantage is you have to make the thread check the file in a loop and it will use a bit resource, the advantage is giving orders is very simple (just write a string to a file) and you don't need to write a client and socket listen server.

Answer (score 0):

[`rpyc`](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the perfect tool for this task.

In short, you define a [`rpyc.Service`](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tut3.html#tut3) class which exposes the commands you want to expose, and start an `rpyc.Server` thread.

Your client then connects to your process, and calls the methods which are mapped to the commands your service exposes.

It's as simple and clean as that. No need to worry about sockets, signals, object serialization.

It has other cool features as well, for example the protocol being symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Your question relates to interprocess communication. You can achieve this by communicating over a unix socket or TCP port, by using a shared memory, or by using a message queue or cache system such as RabbitMQ and Redis.

[This post](http://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/) talks about using mmap to achieve shared memory interprocess communication.

Here's how to get started with [redis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html), both are rather simple to implement.